# How do I get the difference of two groups in one dataframe (longtable) in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this given dataframe:

```
  days classtype scores
1    1         a     49
2    1         b     47
3    2         a     36
4    2         b     41
```

It is produce by this given code:

```
days=c(1,1,2,2)
classtype=c("a","b","a","b")
scores=c(49,47,36,41)
myData=data.frame(days,classtype,scores)
print(myData)
```

What lines do I need to add to the code in order to get calculate the difference in scores of the two classes for each day? I want to get this output:

```
  days difference_in_scores
1    1                    2
2    2                   -5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

days=c(1,1,2,2)
classtype=c("a","b","a","b")
scores=c(49,47,36,41)
myData=data.frame(days,classtype,scores)

myData %>% 
  # convert the data to wide format
  dcast(days ~ classtype, 
        value.var = "scores") %>% 
  # calculate differences
  mutate(difference_in_scores = a - b) %>% 
  # remove columns (just to match your desired output)
  select(days, difference_in_scores)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format of your data is consistently as you have shown then you can accomplish this very neatly using `data.table`:

```
setDT(myData)
myData[, diff(scores), by = days]
   days V1
1:    1 -2
2:    2  5
```

Or using just **base-R**:

```
aggregate(scores ~ days, myData, FUN = diff)
```